# How to downcast RefPtr

Tags: c++, treeview, glib, gtkmm

In Gtk I have a class hierarchy like this:

Gtk::ListStore is derived from Gtk::TreeModel

From a `Gtk::TreeView` I can get with `get_model()` a `Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TreeModel>`

If I use in my `Gtk::Treeview` a   Gtk::ListStore as a Gtk::TreeModel and call `get_model()`I get a `Glib::RefPtr< TreeModel >`

But I want call member functions of Gtk::ListStore.

How can I cast the `Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TreeModel>` down to `Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore>`. Is there a standard way or is there a hack needed or how is the typical procedure to act with views and different store types. Are there any checking functions so that the upcast can done safe, maybe with compile time checking or if not possible during runtime? Any hint to any documentation.

Comment: Casting from a base class to a derived class is a downcast, not an upcast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For downcasting use

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore> ptrDerived = Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore>::cast_dynamic(treeModel);
```

[documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.9/sec-refptr-casting.html.en)

Answer (score 2):

Upcasting is implicit as shown in the documentation linked by nikitoz.

However, `Gtk::ListStore` is not a base class of `Gtk::TreeModel` but other way round. You are asking about downcasting, not upcasting. For that, you need explicit dynamic cast. `Glib::RefPtr` has a static member function template `cast_dynamic` which does exactly that. You can find it in the [class reference](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/2.40/classGlib_1_1RefPtr.html#a07c06c5c305e65d6149a139c462a78d1)